# new WP_Query issues

Tags: categories, wp-query, query-posts

My default wordpress set hold 10 posts per page.

In category.php , I want to override this with 999 post per page, the problem is that isn't working at all.

When I use the following code. it doesn't adjust alphabetically or shows 999 posts

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

<section id="index" class="index">
  <div class="wrap">

    <div class="filter">

      <dl id="filters" class="dropdown drop-model">
        <dt><a href="#"><span>Selecciona el modelo de tu auto</span><small>&#9662;
        </small></a></dt>
        <dd>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="" data-filter="*">Todos</a></li>
            <li><ul class="thead-inside"><li>Modelo</li><li>Version</li><li>Año</li></ul></li>
            <?php
            global $query_string;

            $args = array(
              'post_per_archive_page' => '999' ,
              'orderby' => 'name',
              'order' => 'ASC'
              );

              $the_query = new WP_Query($query_string,$args); ?>

              <?php
              if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
              ?>
              <li><a href="#" data-filter=".<?php theSlug(); ?>-<?php getYearTire(); ?>">
                <ul class="tr-inside">
                  <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
                  <li><?php the_version(); ?></li>
                  <li><?php getYearTire(); ?></li></ul>
                </a>
              </li>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

          </ul>
        </dd>
      </dl>
  </div>

  <article class="clearfix">
   <ul class="getTire thead">
    <li>Auto</li>
    <li>Modelo</li>
    <li>Version</li>
    <li>A&ntilde;o</li>
    <li>Medida</li>
    <!-- <li>Tipo</li> -->
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</article>

<div class="events" id="events">
  <?php
  global $query_string;

  $args = array(
    'post_per_archive_page' => '999' ,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query($query_string,$args); ?>
    <?php
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    ?>

    <article class="<?php theSlug(); ?>-<?php getYearTire(); ?> <?php the_version(); ?> <?php the_options(); ?> clearfix">
      <figure><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></figure>
      <ul class="getTire">
        <li><?php the_category(', '); ?></li>
        <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
        <li><?php the_version(); ?></li>
        <li><?php getYearTire(); ?></li>
        <li><?php whohaveit(); ?></li>
        <!--  <li><?php// the_type(); ?></li> -->
        <li><input class="btn" value="Busca" onclick="window.location='/tienda/product-tag/<?php simple_tag(); ?>'"></li>
      </ul>
    </article>


  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>


<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>




</div>
</section>
<div class="hidden" id="slider"></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your query is that `new WP_Query($query_string,$args);` is not correct syntax, however, creating a new `WP_Query` is not the way to do what you want. See the codex page for [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) for the correct way to modify the main query.

I assume by setting posts per page to 999, you want to show all posts, so just use `-1` instead to remove the limit from the query. This would go in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function wpa90381_category_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'name' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa90381_category_query' );
```

Comment: Hey @Milo thanks again.... it worked like charm... now i have to make look this better, 'cos with all post showing it looks awful. [http://tirego.mx/category/audi](http://tirego.mx/category/audi)